# How do I get the integer method "guess" to go into another method as an array?

Tags: arrays, methods, integer

```
else {
   masterNum[3] = guess % 10; //checks integers in their respective positions
   masterNum[2] = ((guess - guess%10)/10)%10;
   masterNum[1] = ((guess - guess % 100)/100)%10;
   masterNum[0] = (guess - guess % 1000)/1000;

   masterDigit(guess, masterNum);
}


//}
//This method determines the total number of correct digits but not 
//necessarily in the correct position


 public static int masterDigit (int [] guess,int [] code) //int [] guess

{

    int i,j,k,number;




    int [] tempGuess = new int [4]; //an array to hold a copy of a code




    boolean found;


    number = 0;
    for(k=0; k<4; k++)              //copies code to tempGuess so code
                                    //doesn't get changed (you can't just assign code to tempGuess)
        tempGuess[k] = code[k];
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
        j=0;
        found = false;
        while(j < 4 && found == false) // a while loop instead of a
                                        // for loop so duplicates are only counted once
        {
            if(guess[i] == tempGuess[j])
            {
                found = true;
                tempGuess[j] = -1; // fills up tempGuess with an impossible 
                                    // value so that index only gets 
                                    // counted once
                number++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

This code is for a Mastermind game with integers. Upon running through the compiler, there is an error saying that integer "guess" cannot be converted to an array. How can I get my guess (defined as an integer scanner console) to go into this method that will check which numbers are correct?

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: Badly indented code